# "Unfortunately My First App has stopped working

Tags: android

I have just downloaded and started using the android SDK and have followed their instructions on creating "my first app" which says "Hello World." I have not changed anything in the code. I am running a Nexus 7 emulator (only one that doesn't crash every time I run it). When I run the app, on the emulator it says "Unfortunately my first app has stopped working."

Here is the logcat:

```
05-16 13:05:48.742: W/dalvikvm(1066): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1559 (ActionBarWindow) in Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable;
05-16 13:05:48.742: D/dalvikvm(1066): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0004
05-16 13:05:48.752: D/AndroidRuntime(1066): Shutting down VM
05-16 13:05:48.752: W/dalvikvm(1066): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2ac5ba8)
05-16 13:05:48.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1066): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-16 13:05:48.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1066): Process: com.example.myfirstapp, PID: 1066
05-16 13:05:48.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1066): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
05-16 13:05:48.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:107)
05-16 13:05:48.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
05-16 13:05:48.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
05-16 13:05:48.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
05-16 13:05:48.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-16 13:05:48.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-16 13:05:48.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-16 13:05:48.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-16 13:05:48.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-16 13:05:48.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-16 13:05:48.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-16 13:05:48.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-16 13:05:48.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-16 13:05:48.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 13:05:48.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-16 13:05:48.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-16 13:05:48.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-16 13:05:48.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-16 13:05:51.822: I/Process(1066): Sending signal. PID: 1066 SIG: 9
```

Any thoughts? Again, this is the default code upon creating a new app, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't work... Thanks for the help

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable` you need to reference AppCompat in your android project properly

Comment: it's complaining about a missing class "android.support.v7.appcompat.R" . These classes belong to what is called "Android Support Library". Check you have support library installed in **Android SDK Manager** and your project properties

Comment: Right click on your project, Click Properties/Android and scroll down to Library. Then add the AppCompat library reference

Comment: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html and https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html for more documentation about this library and setting it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved this problem:

1. Import support library as a project from
   "sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat".
2. Reference library in your project (for Eclipse, "Properties -
   Android - Add").
3. Build projects (for Eclipse, "Projects - Build All"). Make sure, you
   have "android.support.v7.appcompat" in your main project gen folder.
4. If it doesn't worked - clean and rebuild project.

and if you have the jar file already in libs folder then first **Delete the jar from the libs folder** and then do the above steps..

Ensure that your in yout Manifest.xml your activity has the correct theme

```
<activity
    android:name="***.*****.******"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
     >
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: got it before you answered, but this is the solution. thanks